# How do I convert SASS variable to native CSS variable while bundling with webpack?

Tags: webpack, sass, node-sass, gulp-sass, webpack-style-loader

I need the bundled file to have native CSS variables in place of SASS variables.
For example I want to replace the SASS variable "$warning" with "var(--warning)" in the output bundled file.

Answer (score 0):

In your SASS file where you define variables you may reorganize definition like this

```
//style.scss

// Define CSS variables
:root {
    --warning: red;
}

// Connect them with SASS variable
$warning: var(--warning);

body {
    color: $warning;
}
```

It will be compiled as

```
:root {
  --warning: red;
}

body {
  color: var(--warning);
}
```

**Note:** for tab-indent SASS syntax (`.sass` files) `:root` will throw syntax error so write it with backslash (`/`) at front

```
// style.sass

\:root 
  --warning: red;
```